# Phonegap in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, cordova-2.0.0

Does anyone know how to make the project template for PhoneGap work in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the reason I cannot open my PhoneGap project is because PhoneGap(Cordova) targets Windows Phone 7.5 and below. Windows Phone development is not supported by default in Visual Studio 2012 and requires a separate installation for Windows Phone 8 [here](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk).

Unfortunately you need to be running Windows 8 for this installation to be successful and as I am still running Windows 7 I have been unable to go further than this. Maybe someone who has this installed can tell us if it works with PhoneGap(Cordova)

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio and Window Phone emulator did not works well at virtual machine. If you installed the emulator on separate partition, you have a better chance to succeed. I am still using Window 7.

You may also referred to the book : Mobile JavaScript Application Development, CH 5, section : PhoneGap - create a Window Phone Application @ page 122 / 168

Good Luck

D

Comment: Where did you see any mention of a virtual machine?

Comment: W Knight, you are off on a tangent here, your answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question